# Find Max value using Measureand use it to define Max value of ScrollBar

Tags: vega-lite, deneb

I am creating a PBI custom visual using Deneb Vegalite.
Since I have many values on the Y axis, I created a scroll bar using Deneb Vega Lite code.

I created a measure to have dynamic index Rank.

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('DPM dump_Jan2023'),
    CALCULATE(SUM('DPM dump_Jan2023'[Index_ProductRel])),
    , ASC, Dense
    )
```

The problem is the static value of max of ScrollBar is set to 60.
Instead of using static value, I would like to make it dynamic.
It should be set to max value of Rank - 10.

I tried

```
"max": {"expr": "max(dataset, 'Rank')"}
```

but this is returning an error.

I also tried joinaggregate but that is also not working.

How do I make this max parameter dynamic based on Rank?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 1000,
  "height": {"step": 35},
  "config": {
    "line": {"strokeWidth": 1}
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "ScrollBar",
      "value": 1,
      "bind": {
        "input": "range",
        "min": 1,
        "max": 60,
        "step": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": "datum.Rank <= ScrollBar + 9 && datum.Rank >= ScrollBar"
    }
  ],
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Date_Roadmap",
      "scale": {"padding": 30},
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {
        "title": "",
        "format": "%b-%Y",
        "domain": true,
        "ticks": true,
        "tickCount": 20,
        "minExtent": 50,
        "maxExtent": 20,
        "labelPadding": 0,
        "labelAngle": -45,
        "labelOverlap": false,
        "labelSeparation": 0,
        "labelFont": "Segoe UI",
        "labelFontSize": 12,
        "labelColor": "black"
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Parents Release_Final",
      "type": "nominal",
      "title": "Parent Release",
      "axis": {
        "offset": 5,
        "ticks": true,
        "labelFontSize": 12,
        "minExtent": 70,
        "domain": true,
        "grid": true,
        "gridDash": [4, 4],
        "gridColor": "#C0D8EE",
        "labelColor": "black"
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "detail": {
          "field": "Parents Release_Final",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
...
```

[Dataset with Rank column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ACiQ.png)

Sample dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v5FJwOcqMeeZOaoV008omHaojdH52btp/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Can you upload a sample .pbix somewhere

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Put all that is needed to ask your question (but only that) in your post, using text for text. A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. Read the edit help re formatting.

Comment: Hi @DavidBacci 
Please find sample PBIX here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MulDkNoWVipTlPbhxUhrwIkAqRrGX-cL/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 0):

Perform a transform on your data first, between the "config" and "params":

```
"config": {
    "line": {"strokeWidth": 1}
},
"insert ": "transform ... blaa blaa ... see below to (watch the close and comma)"],
"params": [
```

and then replace `"max": 60` with `"max": {"expr": "MaxRankValue"}`.

```
"transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {
          "op": "max",
          "field": "Rank",
          "as": "MaxRank"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.MaxRank[0]",
      "as": "MaxRankValue"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to say about the `"config"` & `"params"` lines. If you want to say, "insert the transform code between those two lines" then just say it, don't write it as if it were code. Be very clear. Use enough words & sentences. Don't write sentence fragments. Use normal font for normal prose & use code font for code. PS Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Comment: @david I tried your solution, but its not working. 
You can find the file where I tried you solution - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MulDkNoWVipTlPbhxUhrwIkAqRrGX-cL/view?usp=drive_link
Refer page name 'deneb_5.2" in the sample PBI.

Comment: @gmp Comments with no @ under the question are for the asker & the comments with no @ under the answer are for the answerer. But I rewrote my comment to the answerer to be clearer so it might be easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using rank / dense_rank. It may be useful for you to understand the transform setup.

You could just replace **10** with a measure from Power BI.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bar chart that sorts the y-values by the x-values.",
  "data": {"url": "data/population.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.year == 2000"},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"op": "sum", "field": "people", "as": "totalPopulation"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["age"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "dense_rank", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "totalPopulation", "order": "descending"}]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.rank <= 10"}
  ],
  "height": {"step": 17},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "age", "type": "ordinal"},
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "people", "title": "population"}
  }
}
```

Comment: This is my first project with Deneb and from the example you shared I could not figured out how I can use this to pass the Max value of 'Rank' Column to Max value of scrollbar.
I also created a measure in dataset 'Max_ScrollBar', but when I pass that to Max value of scrollbar, it shows validation errors.
Could you please modify the code/suggest line of code.

Comment: Is it even possible to pass dynamically calculated value or PBI measure value to ScrollBar max ?